# Developing unit-test for node js using mocha, supertest with async/await functions, but i am getting error "Resolution method is overspecified"

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

Developing unit-test for NodeJs REST API using mocha, supertest with async/await functions, but i am getting below error,
I am using arrow functions with async and await keywords.

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified.
```

So someone could help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `async` function by default returns a promise and you call the done function manually as well which confuses Mocha as to when the test is actually finished. Please see the issue [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2407). A quick-and-dirty solution would be to wrap the async function in another, not async function like this:

```js
it("should work", done => {
  (async () => {
    await something;
    done();
  })();
});
```

But the better way would be to compose promises in such a way that the returned from the async function promise resolves in the right moment of time and not to call the done callback manually at all.

Comment: Or declare the test function as async: `it('should work', async () => { await something })`

Comment: @robertklep, I'm trying what I believe you're suggesting but with no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55232992/how-do-i-structure-tests-for-asynchronous-functions