# How do I structure tests for asynchronous functions?

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js, assert

I'm accustomed to writing Mocha tests using the standard NodeJs *assert* library like this:

```
describe('Some module', () => {
   var result = someCall();
   it('Should <something>', () => {
      assert.ok(...);
   });
})
```

but now my call returns a promise... so I want to write:

```
describe('Some module', async () => {
   var result = await someCall();
   it('Should <something>', () => {
      assert.ok(...);
   });
})
```

but it doesn't work.  My tests don't run at all.  Curiously,

```
describe('Some module', async () => {
   it('Should <something>', () => {
      var result = await someCall();
      assert.ok(...);
   });
})
```

works fine but the problem is that I want to make a single call and run many tests against it, so I want to make the call outside the it() calls

How do I make it work?

and *please* don't recommend Chai.  I want to use the standard assert library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`before` accepts an `async` function so you can get the `result` before your tests run and use it in your tests like this:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const someCall = () => Promise.resolve('hi');

describe('Some module', () => {
  let result;

  before(async () => {
    result = await someCall();
  });

  it('Should <something>', () => {
    assert.equal(result, 'hi');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Although a little unconventional in use, one approach might be to use the [`before()` hook](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) to achieve what you require.

The `before()` hook would provide a means of calling functionality (ie `someCall()`) prior to the rest of the tests in your suite. The hook itself supports execution of asynchronous functionality via a callback function (ie `done`) that can be called once asynchronous functionality has completed:

```
before((done) => {
  asyncCall().then(() => {
    /* Signal to the framework that async call has completed */
    done(); 
  });
});
```

One way to integrate this with your existing code might be as follows:

```
describe("Some module", () => {
  /* Stores result of async call for subsequent verification in tests */
  var result;

  /* User before hook to run someCall() once for this suite, and
  call done() when async call has completed */
  before((done) => {
    someCall().then((resolvedValue) => {
      result = resolvedValue;
      done();
    });
  });

  it("Should <something>", () => {

    /* result variable now has resolved value ready for verification */
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You don't need to use `done` in `before` if `asyncCall` returns a `Promise`. Just return the `Promise`. `before(() => {
  return asyncCall().then(() => {
    // do some stuff before moving to it
  });
});` Other than that +1, I'd use `before` too.

Comment: @NikKyriakides thanks for the feedback :-) I originally opted for the `async/await` based approach that you mention however it didn't seem to work in my environment (though it should have), where as the posted solution did. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Yes you need to **return** a Promise if you're not using `done`. Since `async` functions already return a `Promise` simply returning `asyncCall` in `before` should suffice. There's no need to use `async/await` in that block.

Comment: Strange - that's what I was doing originally. I may need to revisit the code on my other workstation tomorrow. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Mocha already supports what you want to do.

Mocha's `describe` function is not designed to work asynchronously. However, the `it` function is designed to work asynchronously either by passing a `done` callback (the actual parameter name can be anything such as "complete" or "resolve" or "done"), returning a promise or passing an `async` function.

Which means your test is ***almost*** correct. You just need to do this instead:

```
describe('Some module', () => {
   it('Should <something>', async () => {
      var result = await someCall();
      assert.ok(...);
   });
})
```

If you need to run the `someCall()` function once for multiple `it` blocks you can do as mentioned in the other answers and call it in a `before` block.